# SparkSQL fourfold table

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I implemented a random forest algorithm to forecast something. 
My DB table after the algorithm:

```
id      order       order_forecast
-----------------------------------------------
1       yes         yes
2       yes         no
3       no          yes
4       no          no
5       yes         yes
6       no          yes
7       yes         no
8       yes         yes
9       yes         yes
```

And now I want to create some kind of fourfold table to check if the random forest was right.

e.g.

```
       yes             no
   -------------------------------
yes  |  4              2
no   |  2              1


Correct classified: 5
Wrong classified: 4
Accuracy: 55,55%
Error:    44,44%
```

Is there any function or any short way to do this?
As I said I am working on a browser interface, I don´t know which DBMS I am using, but I found out that window functions are working.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table, then:

```
select order, order_forecast, count(*)
from results r
group by order, order_forecast;
```

This produces four rows rather than two.  You can then do the additional calculations in the application.

To get the data in your specific format, then use:

```
select order,
       sum(case when order_forecast = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end) as yes,
       sum(case when order_forecast = 'no' then 1 else 0 end) as no
from results
group by order;
```

Or just get the correctness directly:

```
select order,
       sum(case when order_forecast = order then 1 else 0 end) as correct,
       sum(case when order_forecast = order then 0 else 1 end) as incorrect
from results
group by order;
```

Note `order` is a really bad name for a column because it is a SQL key word.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it on monday at work, no worries I just translated the column into english, on the DB its called 'auftrag'